# ps wide output for a single process

Tags: linux, ps

The ps command has a `ww` output modifier (man page says this is "wide output, unlimited length"). This modifier seems to not work if prefixed with a hyphen (`-ww`) *AND* ps reports on a *single* process (with the `-p` option).

For more than one process *OR* if a hyphen *isn't* used, it works.

Why so? Have I misunderstood what "wide output" means? This is on Redhat RHEL 6.5.

```
$ ps -w -p 2180
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2180 tty1     00:00:00 mingetty

$ ps -w -p 2180 2182
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2180 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
 2182 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
```

An output format specifier changes from 'CMD' to 'COMMAND', depending on whether one or more PIDs were fed to '-p'.

Answer (score 12):

`ps` has two syntaxes, the BSD and the System V syntax.  If you start your options with a hyphen, you are using System V syntax.  The `w` flag is a BSD syntax flag.  In BSD syntax, you can just specify the process ID without any option.  So I think the command you just want is:

```
ps ww 2180 2182
```

(where 2180, 2182 are example PIDs).

Comment: … and if you give a non-option argument PID, you get (sloppy) SysV syntax again, right?  Hence `ps -w -p 2180 2182` is (sloppy) SysV syntax, while `ps -w -p 2180 -p 2182` (where each PID has a `-p`) is BSD syntax.  … right?

Comment: Thanks user318..., the issue seems to an output format specifier is switched from COMMAND to CMD if a single process is reported on in my example. Switching to a 'pure BSD' format works fine (i.e. drop the "-p", or remove the hyphen from "-w").

Comment: Thanks 'The Sid...'. But " ps -w -p" seems to force the use of the CMD output format specifier (does not report the command line) by default

Comment: I think its a bug in ps implementation (The man page states "-ww" and "ww" are equivalent, yet default output format specifier changes if more than one process is reported on).

Comment: @Happyblue: I think having two totally different modes is confusing, but the man page is correct.  It says "BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash."  So even though the descriptions of w and -w are the same, the two options are not the same (one is BSD, one UNIX).  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html

Comment: I accept the man page is correct. It does state options can be mixed. The issue is that if pure UNIX options are being used (-w and -p), the output format specifier changes (from CMD to COMMAND), depending on if 1 or more PIDs appeared after '-p' (a PID list is legal). So this behavior is strange even with pure UNIX options.

Comment: I think the problem is that a bare PID that isn't an option argument is a BSD option.  So if you say `ps -p 2180 -p 2182`, you are using Unix syntax.  But if you say `ps -p 2180 2182`, the bare 2182 is a BSD option, which is why you get BSD-format output.

Comment: Thanks @user3188445!